# Wrong code coverage covered by istanbul

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, istanbul

I have configured tool karma-coverage to measure my code coverage. Hovewer I have noticed that in some cases it does not recognize whether my code was called during testing or not. Here is the sample which I have used in my tests:

This test was not detected by Istanbul correctly:

```
it('should throw an error if credentials.username is not defined', function() {
   expect(function(){
       currentAuthProvider.authenticate({
           password: '123456'
       }).toThrowError('Parameter credentials.username should be defined.')
   });
});
```

I have changed the test to this form, which was captured correctly:

```
it('should throw an error if credentials.username is not defined', function() {
   try{
      currentAuthProvider.authenticate({
         password: '123456'
      })
   } catch(e){
         expect(e.message).toEqual('Parameter credentials.username should be defined.');
   }
});
```

I would like to write my tests in form as the 1st test is. In 1st case the code coverage was showing that currentAuhProvider.authenticate function was not covered by unit tests, but in 2nd case the correct result was shown in code coverage result. Is there any other way how to influence Istanbul to detect the first test and compute it into code coverage as well?